# is_floating_point specialization for user defined type

Tags: c++, c++17

Can I define is_floating_point for user defined class? I tried this. But is_floating_point returns false.

```
class Test
{
  public:
  Test() { x = 0; }
  private:
    float x;
};

template<>
struct is_floating_point<Test>
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

void main()
{
   std::cout<<std::is_floating_point<Test>::value<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Make your own `is_floating_point` that allows the normal floating points and your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `std::is_floating_point<T>` is [defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.cat) to return true when "T is a floating point type", and the standard then [states](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#12) that "There are three floating-point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

Doesn't leave any wiggle room.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) also makes that clear: "_The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `is_floating_point` (or `is_floating_point_v`) is undefined._"